# What does "worth a google" really means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Joker reveals all his team before the *pilot* whose plane hijacked by him.

> Joker: Orca, Killer Motharch Harriet, Zodiac Master,Gentleman
>   Ghost,Clock King, Calendar Man, Kite-Man, Catman, Zebra-Man, and the
>   Condiment King
>
> Pilot: Okay, are you making some of those up?
>
> Joker: Nope, they're all real. Probably **worth a Google**.

Answer (score 2):

To be *[worth](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/worth_1)* something is to say that deserves or merits an attempt, as used in common phrases like

- worth a try
- worth a look
- worth a go
- worth the time
- worth the effort
- [something was] worth it

In the context given, *a Google* almost certainly refers to *a [world-wide] web search*, as the popularity and dominance of the Google search engine has led to its use as a generic verb for any broad search of the web, as well as the assumption that it will probably be conducted using Google.

The use of trade names to refer to activities or classes of products is not uncommon; someone may *photoshop* a "selfie" (i.e. use software to alter a photograph) or *xerox* a presentation (i.e. make a photocopy of something). You can find [*Google* in the dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/google) as a verb. In some cases, the usage becomes so genericized that the word loses trademark protection in various countries, as has occurred with *videotape* and *heroin* among others.

The Joker, in short, is saying that the pilot would do well to undertake the (minimal) effort to search for the names on the Internet, perhaps for the pilot's own edification or entertainment, or perhaps because the knowledge is necessary to avoid some dire consequence.